# SQL Query to retrieve users based on date and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have the following table:

**User**

- UserID
- CompanyID
- Name
- IsActive
- Date_Joined
- Date_Left

I'm trying to get a query to get the billable users, criteria being:

- A user that joined the month of billing, is not seen as a billable user.
- A user that left on the month of billing, **is** a billable user.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * from user u WHERE CompanyID = 1205
AND (p.IsActive = 1 AND MONTH(p.Date_Joined) != MONTH(GETDATE())
OR (p.is_active = 0 AND MONTH(p.Date_Left) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

The problem is that this query isn't working as it doesn't check the year of the user (users joined in september 2017 are not seen as billable, even though they should as they were joined in 2017 and not this year, the persons who are created in september 2018 should not be seen as billable).

How can I implement the year or optimize my query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be used to determine the last day of month. For example:

```
/* last day of prev month */ EOMONTH('2018-09-05', -1) = 2018-08-31
/* last day of curr month */ EOMONTH('2018-09-05')     = 2018-09-30
```

You can easily check if active user joined on previous month(s) or inactive user left on current month as follows:

```
DECLARE @billdate AS DATE = '2018-09-05';

SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE CompanyID = 1205 AND (
    (
        IsActive = 1 AND 
        Date_Joined <= EOMONTH(@billdate, -1)
    )
    OR
    (
        IsActive = 0 AND 
        Date_Left >  EOMONTH(@billdate, -1) AND
        Date_Left <= EOMONTH(@billdate)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your query, but if I launch this on my table, i do not get the persons that left this month (and so are still billable). If the person left on the month of `GETDATE()`, it needs to be billed

Comment: Thanks this looks good but I wanted to know how I could test this to simulate different invoicing month, do I increase the `-1` to simulate later months?

Comment: `-1` should not be touched. Replace `GETDATE()` with a user variable e.g. `DECLARE @billdate AS DATE = '2018-01-01';` and replace all instances of `GETDATE()` with `@billdate`.

Comment: Great! This is starting to look perfect! The problem is that I get users from other companies even with the `WHERE CompanyID=1205`-clause, does this mean I need to add `AND CompanyID = 1205` for every clause?

Comment: No, what I meant is that I only want the users of CompanyID 1205, but your query returns rows with users from other CompanyID (what I do not want).

Comment: The `OR` conditions should be enclosed in parentheses. Right now it's a `CompanyID=1205 AND Condition1 OR Condition2`. It should be `CompanyID ... AND (Condition1 or Condition2)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos correct... I messed up the parenthesis.

Comment: @SalmanA I have one more small question (sorry for disturbing you with this), but I want also the possibility to allow users that are leaving in the future (to allow future invoicing). do you confirm that I can do this by adding : `OR( is_active = 0 AND date_left >= EOMONTH(@billdate))` ?

Comment: @SalmanA I have one more small question (sorry for disturbing you with this), but I want also the possibility to allow users that are leaving in the future (to allow future invoicing). do you confirm that I can do this by adding : `OR( is_active = 0 AND date_left >= EOMONTH(@billdate,-1) AND date_joined != EOMONTH(@billdate, -1))` ? **

Comment: Can you give me an example (date of billing and date when user left)?

Answer (score 0):

- I think your parenthesis are off. Putting them around an `AND` doesn't do anything. You probably wanted to put them around the `OR`.
- There is no target table for the alias `p`. From the column names I think the columns prefixed with it are also from `user`, so change the alias to `u`.
- And to check the year you can use `year()` similar to how you used `month()`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM user u
       WHERE u.companyid = 1205
             AND (u.isactive = 1
                  AND month(p.date_joined) != month(getdate())
                  AND year(p.date_joined) = year(getdate())
                   OR u.is_active = 0
                      AND month(p.date_left) = month(getdate())
                      AND year(p.date_left) = year(getdate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need check between current month start date and End date.
Try this

```
DECLARE @D_FROM_DATE DATE,@D_TO_DATE DATE

SELECT @D_FROM_DATE=DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()-1),GETDATE()),
@D_TO_DATE=DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()))

    SELECT * FROM USER P
    WHERE P.COMPANYID = 1205
    AND 
    (
        CAST(P.DATE_JOINED AS DATE) BETWEEN  @D_FROM_DATE AND @D_TO_DATE
        OR 
        CAST(P.DATE_LEFT AS DATE) BETWEEN  @D_FROM_DATE AND @D_TO_DATE
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this

```
SELECT * from user u WHERE CompanyID = 1205
AND (p.IsActive = 1 AND CONCAT(YEAR(p.Date_Joined),'/',MONTH(p.Date_Joined)) != CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),'/',MONTH(GETDATE())))
OR (p.is_active = 0 AND CONCAT(YEAR(p.Date_Left),'/',MONTH(p.Date_Left)) = CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),'/',MONTH(GETDATE())))
```